# How to get certain keys from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I need to extract certain keys from each of the dictionaries in the list.

The list of dictionaries looks like so:

```
[{u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/', u'abbreviation': u'PC', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/', u'id': 94, u'name': u'PC'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-35/', u'abbreviation': u'PS3', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/playstation-3/3045-35/', u'id': 35, u'name': u'PlayStation 3'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-20/', u'abbreviation': u'X360', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/xbox-360/3045-20/', u'id': 20, u'name': u'Xbox 360'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-86/', u'abbreviation': u'XBGS', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/xbox-360-games-store/3045-86/', u'id': 86, u'name': u'Xbox 360 Games Store'}]
```

How would I go about getting all the 'name' keys out of there?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple:

```
for elem in list:
    print elem['name']
```

Comment: +1 to you -  often wise to add a check that the key is in the element before doing anything as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all names, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [{u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/', u'abbreviation': u'PC', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/', u'id': 94, u'name': u'PC'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-35/', u'abbreviation': u'PS3', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/playstation-3/3045-35/', u'id': 35, u'name': u'PlayStation 3'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-20/', u'abbreviation': u'X360', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/xbox-360/3045-20/', u'id': 20, u'name': u'Xbox 360'}, {u'api_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-86/', u'abbreviation': u'XBGS', u'site_detail_url': u'http://www.giantbomb.com/xbox-360-games-store/3045-86/', u'id': 86, u'name': u'Xbox 360 Games Store'}]
>>> [D['name'] for D in L]
['PC', 'PlayStation 3', 'Xbox 360', 'Xbox 360 Games Store']
```

If `name` is not in every dictionary, you can filter the dictionaries:

```
>>> [D['name'] for D in L if 'name' in D]
['PC', 'PlayStation 3', 'Xbox 360', 'Xbox 360 Games Store']
```